# How to include a html file in another. I've tried a lot of codes. Nothing

Tags: html, include

I have file named `a.html` with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Restaurant Gaststätte Gartenfreunde-Ehningen</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="generator" content="iloapp 2.1"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ilostatic.one.com/iloapp/gallery/images/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"/>
</head>
<body>
<script>
   (function () {
     var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.src = '//ilostatic.one.com/iloapp/gallery/js/init.js?' + (new Date).getTime();
     document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(script);
  })();
</script>
<noscript><iframe src="//ilostatic.one.com/iloapp/gallery/html/nojs_1_en-US.html" frameBorder="0" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe></noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

It`s for a galerie who look like this: [link](http://galerie.restaurant-gartenfreunde-ehningen.de/#!album-0)

I want to include this here: [link](http://restaurant-gartenfreunde-ehningen.de/galerie.html)

Need some help here.

Comment: Do you just want to add that link for it to be clicked or you want to include the HTML/CSS code from the link in the code you posted above?

Comment: No! I want to include that code i've posted above (/galerie/index.html) in another file (/galerie.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jquery you can do the following:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

If you are looking to do raw Javascript DOM then you can do the following:

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", "b.html", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Alredy tried! No work! I can include any file, but not that witch contain the code i've posted above! I've maked that photo galierie automatic with a program by the site who offer me hosting, and only file i've got from them is index.html who contain the code i've posted. They ofered me a code to embed that galerie to my page, but it looks like a movie.

Comment: My english is not so perfect so I will try to explain better:
I have that galerie who is created automatic by a site: http://galerie.restaurant-gartenfreunde-ehningen.de/#!home (this is the link)
I want this page to apear here: [http://restaurant-gartenfreunde-ehningen.de/galerie.html] and i can't redirect that page, but i want to keep some things like 'menu bar'. To edit the file for galerie i can't, because i have no css file for that, so only choise is to include that galerie in my galerie site page.

Comment: Done! with iframe :) (y)

Answer (score 1):

> You could include an HTML code from another file without scripting using SSI ([Sever
>   Side Includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes)).

Just name your file with `.shtml` extension and write something like at the place you want to include your file (e.g. index.html):

```
<!--#include virtual="/galerie/index.html" -->
```

Usually SSI works in `.shtml` files by default without any configuration.

Web server will work up `.shtml` file, looks for SSI directives inside it and process them.

Comment: Alredy tried! This site how maked my galerie i think have something integrated in script to be not allowed integrated that

Comment: How particularly did you find this out? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

I've succesfull integrated galerie in script. :) Thanks all guys for youre tips. I've used iframe . Finaly worked

Comment: Please provide your working solution for future visitors of this question.